# как быстрее обращаться к данным в строке DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, clr

Во время прорисовки компонента нужно использовать некоторые значения текущей строки из набора данных DataTable (допустим, построчно). Как быстрее будет обращаться среда к данным строки dataRow[...] - через индекс колонки, его имя, сам класс DataColumn? 
Где можно почитать про разбор таких механизмов?

Comment: Вы пытаетесь экономить на спичках, и особенно бессмысленным это выглядит на фоне того, что всё это связано с работой с базами данных. Эти ваши ухищрения с индексаторами и индексами, даже если какой-то из этих вариантов чуть быстрее остальных, не идут ни в какое сравнение со временем обращения к бд, и разница там составит тысячи, если не миллионы раз. Простая аналогия - вы приходите в магазин и, не долго думая, покупаете там огромный телевизор за 100 тысяч рублей. А потом мучительно и скрупулёзно выбираете розетку и в попытке сэкономить решаете купить розетку не за 50 рублей, а за 45

Comment: Посмотрите на исходники [DataRow](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/DataRow.cs), конкретно — на индексаторы. Беглый взгляд показывает, что по индексу колонки быстрее всего. Но @DreamChild прав — разница незначительная.

Comment: Спасибо, все ясно! можно оформить как ответ